# Library Dependencies bundled together to create jar file is not present in the jar file using sbt-assembly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have multiple libraries dependency in the sbt.build file. I am creating the final jar file using sbt-assembly so it includes all the dependent libraries in the jar itself.

But using `jar tvf jarname.jar`, I am not able to find all libraries there.

I need this to bundle all libraries in a jar and provide it to `spark-shell` with `spark-shell --jar jarpath` and then using the import command to use the libraries there.

This is done because this is not possible for me to import packages directly to spark-shell
using the `spark-shell --packages` command.

Expected:
Adding the jar file to the spark-shell and then importing all libraries there which should be present in jar

Comment: *"this is not possible for me to import packages directly to spark-shell using the `spark-shell --packages` command"* Why?

Comment: It could be helpful if you add your `build.sbt` and mention what specific library is missing from assembly jar.

Comment: @DmytroMitin This is because my linux server don't have the access to internet. Anyways found the solution here. Some of there dependencies were marked "provided" and thus not included in the jar. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What command you use to generate jar, and where are you tried to see it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here:

Some of my dependencies includes the "provided" tag and thus it was not getting included in the fat jar.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-table-planner" % flinkVersion % "provided"
```